# What is the best practice when initializing co-dependent objects?

Tags: java

I've been trying to improve my (currently poor) java skills by creating a practice android app. In my app each screen is managed by a single class which manages processing inputs, logic, and rendering.

For some classes, it was becoming too large to be easily understood, so I decided to move the code into several categorized classes which are called as objects in the main screen class. For example:

```
public class Screen {

 ScreenA a;
 ScreenB b;
 ScreenC c;

 public Screen() {
  a = new ScreenA();
  b = new ScreenB();
  c = new ScreenC();
 }

 public void doStuff() {
  a.method();
  b.method();
  c.method();
 }
}
```

What I am trying to understand is whether this is the right way to improve code legibility, and whether it has any impact on memory usage/processing speed. For example, would calling static methods be a better option?

Additionally, does the answer change when the classes are dependent on each other? E.g. if methods in ScreenB need to call variables or methods in ScreenA? I would have though either of the two examples below would be suitable, but I do not know what is best practice:

```
public class Screen {

 ScreenA a;
 ScreenB b;
 ScreenC c;

 public Screen(){
  a = new ScreenA();
  b = new ScreenB(a);
  c = new ScreenC(a,b);
 }

 public void doStuff(){
  a.method();
  b.method();
  c.method();
 }
}

public class ScreenB {

 ScreenA a;

 public ScreenB(ScreenA a) {
  this.a = a;
 }
}
```

or:

```
public class Screen {

 ScreenA a;
 ScreenB b;
 ScreenC c;

 public Screen(){
  a = new ScreenA();
  b = new ScreenB();
  c = new ScreenC();
 }

 public void doStuff(){
  a.method();
  b.method(a);
  c.method(a,b);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> What I am trying to understand is whether this is the right way to
>   improve code legibility, and whether it has any impact on memory
>   usage/processing speed. For example, would calling static methods be a better option?

What you've done is essentially splitting different responsibilities in different classes and enclosing behaviour. This is what OOP is all about, and Java is built for OOP. Instantiating objects has a cost compared to calling static methods but you should never be afraid of doing it. Static methods do not allow encapsulation, inheritance, dependency injection and many other things which make an OO application a good software.

> Additionally, does the answer change when the classes are dependent on
>   each other? E.g. if methods in ScreenB need to call variables or
>   methods in ScreenA? I would have though either of the two examples
>   below would be suitable, but I do not know what is best practice

One rule of thumb for deciding parameters versus class attribute is the following: are you always going to use the same parameters ? If yes, they're not parameters, they're a state and should be passed to the constructor. If no, then they may be used as parameters.

Another good indicator is: how many methods are going to need the same parameters to implement their function ? If there are many methods requiring these parameters, attributes may make more sense than parameters.